# Can you enchant arrows?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to enchant arrows in Minecraft Pocket Edition? If so what enchantments can you use?

Comment: Please answer eventually

Comment: Please don't fill the question body with noise. If you're struggling to write something, at least tell us which platform you're playing on. You've tagged this question with Minecraft (Java version) and Minecraft Pocket Edition. These are 2 completely different versions of the game.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Arrow

Comment: The question is not unclear (anymore), but it is still too broad, taking into account the second part of your question.

Comment: @Gavin there is an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot enchant [Arrows](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow). However, you can craft [Tipped Arrows](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow#Tipped_arrows). It is crafted by putting a [Lingering Potion](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lingering_Potion) in the middle of the crafting table, and arrows all around it. You can also craft [Spectral Arrows](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow#Spectral_arrows) by using [Glowstone Dust](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowstone_Dust) instead of a [Lingering Potion](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lingering_Potion).